# iomanip affecting ctime function output unexpectedly

Tags: c++

My goal is to use `<iomanip>` to set a width of 50 or so spaces and have `<ctime>` print the date and time, however when doing so `<iomanip>` doesn't work as intended. I used `<iomanip>` in this same fashion, outputting characters, for previous outputs and it worked fine so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong now.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void dateTime(){
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm* dt = localtime(&now);
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(56) << left << 1900 + dt->tm_year << "/" << 1 + dt->tm_mon << "/" << dt->tm_mday << ", " << dt->tm_hour << ":" << dt->tm_min << " |" << endl;
  }

int main()
{
  dateTime();
}
```

Output I'm getting (incorrect):

```
2016                                                    /1/6, 17:36 |
```

Expected output (correct):

```
2016/1/6, 17:36                                                     |
```

Comment: You need to include both the code and the expected output (as well as the incorrect output you're getting) in the question, not as external links.

Comment: @KeithThompson better?

Comment: Better -- and even more so now.  I updated your question to include the *complete* program and the actual and expected output, all in the body of the question with no external links.

Comment: @KeithThompson oh okay, that does look alot better, I'll keep that in mind next time, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `std::setw` affects the width of field for only one output, not the entire group of outputs that comprise the date/time you care about. Fortunately, the standard provides a very clean way to handle the problem: the `std::put_time` manipulator creates a single result containing the fields you care about, so with it, you can format your output something like this:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void dateTime() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm* dt = localtime(&now);

    std::cout << std::setw(56) << std::put_time(dt, "%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M") << "|";
}

int main()
{
    dateTime();
}
```

...which produces output like this:

```
2016/01/06, 17:48                                                       |
```

Comment: Thank-you, I was almost at the answer aha, I didn't know you could have multiple conversion specifiers in 1 call of put_time.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own `ignore_manipulator` stream object, that would prevent output to be manipulated from `iomanip`. Here's my implementation in [vrm_core, one of my C++14 libraries](https://github.com/SuperV1234/vrm_core/tree/master/include/vrm/core/ostream_utils).

---

Stripped down implementation:

```
struct ignore_manipulator
{
    std::string _str;

    ignore_manipulator(const std::string& str) 
        : _str(str) 
    { 
    }

    auto& operator=(const std::string& str)
    {
        _str = str;
        return *this;
    }

    operator const T&() const noexcept
    {
        return _str;
    }

    auto begin() const noexcept
    {
        return std::begin(_str);
    }

    auto end() const noexcept
    {
        return std::end(_str);
    }
};

template <typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& o, const ignore_manipulator& im)
{
    // `o.put` ignores manipulators.
    for(const auto& c : im) o.put(c);
    return o;
}
```

Usage example:

```
// "hello" won't be affected by previous manipulators.
cout << setfill(' ') << setw(56) << ignore_manipulator("hello") << "\n";
```

Comment: I want the output to be manipulated, I think I figured out my issue though.